# Sorting in reverse order of compound index still valid?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have a compound index like so: `{ a: -1, b: -1, c: -1 }` can I sort by `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }` and still use the compound index? Essentially, keeping the order and relative sort the same, just in reverse order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MongoDB can use the compound index for a reverse sort on the indexed keys.

If you have a compound index on:

```
 db.test.ensureIndex({a: -1, b: -1, c: -1})
```

The results of `explain` indicate that a `BTreeCursor` was used

```
db.test.find().sort({a: 1, b:1, c:1}).explain()

      "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_-1_b_-1_c_-1 reverse",
      "isMultiKey" : false,
      "n" : 11,
      "nscannedObjects" : 11,
      "nscanned" : 11,
      "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 11,
...
```

The compound index will be used if you reverse the sort order of all of the index prefixes.

However, `db.test.find().sort({a:1, b: 1, c: -1})`, won't be able use the index and hence will use a `BasicCursor`.